SharePoint column show/hide condition - Multiple conditions with OR
I have a Choice column that I want to display if either of two conditions are true.
It's an Approver Response column that I want to hide if "Approver Notified" checkbox = false, and Status = "Pending".
So far I have: =if([$ApproverNotified] == false, 'false', 'true').
How would I modify this to Hide if either Approver Notified = false OR Status = "Pending"?
Status is a Choice column.

Try: =if([$ApproverNotified] == false || [$Status] == 'Pending', 'false', 'true'). Let me know if it works for you.

If you are trying to use OR condition, try using formula like:
=if([$ApproverNotified] == false || [$Status] == 'Pending', 'false', 'true')

Where [$ApproverNotified] and [$Status] is an internal name of your columns in SharePoint list in this format: [$InternalNameOfColumn].
You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?.
Documentation: Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library form

Thank you for the reply.  This unfortunately didn't quite work - This made the column visible at all times.  When a new doc set is created, power automate updates ApproverNotified to true.  Once a response has been given (radio button), power automate then updates the Status column to Pending.

Can you explain conditions to show/hide column from list/library from once again? As per the question, column should be visible when either "ApproverNotified" checkbox (Yes/No column) is unchecked OR "Status" column is equal to "Pending". Is this understanding correct?

Sure thing - yeah it's kind of confusing.  So this is when I want The Approver Response column (the column I'm giving this formula to) to HIDE: If ApproverNotified (Y/N) = false OR Status (Choice) = "Pending".

In that case, the formula provided above should work. Are you using correct internal names for columns? Status column is single selection or multiple selection choice column?

Yeah the logic in your formula seems like it should work...so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.  This is the formula I applied (with the actual column names):  =if([$Approver1Notified] == false || [$RI_x0020_Decision] == 'Pending', 'false', 'true') .  When I open a new Doc Set form, that field is displaying (RI Decision, or Status, is = "New", and Approver Notified = false.

The choice column is single select, and does not allow write-ins

Are both Approver1Notified and RI Decision columns visible on the "form"?

Actually no.  Neither are visible on the form

That might be the reason. Can you try adding those fields on the form for testing purpose and see if provided formula works? I think column/field should be visible on the form if you want to refer value of it in the formula.

I just made those other two fields visible in the form, so I could visually check to make sure the conditions were met, but I had the same result.  I'm trying to think of an alternative...maybe rather than a formula to hide that field, is there a way I could make it read-only when those two conditions are met?  This stuff is very simple with PowerApps, but I'm stuck with the SP Default form due to having to create a doc set with metadata

You cannot make read only using SharePoint default form capabilities.
